# PHP Uploading Files Until Server Full

Tags: php

I have one problem. People can upload files as attachment on my website to contact us/mail us (list displayed once uploaded etc). There is upload limit for one session, but if another one is created (it's more like random id) you can start over uploading to the server. So basically you can upload thousand files until the server is full.

Is there a possible way to prevent this? You can limit it for one  IP or cookie, but I can have another one and this is still a problem.

Thank you

Comment: Are the files attached in the email? if so, don't keep the files after the script has finished processing, and implement a garbage collection routine.

Comment: Basically it's a regular file upload, example with images you can see your uploaded image as image etc. Once you press sent the uploads are attached to the mail().

Comment: I am also suspicious about these free just upload sites, how they have free space left.

Comment: Allow uploads only to registered users and limit their uploads